# can't find ros package in kinetic driver-base

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find the package, in the ros site , I saw it not maintainable.

How can i migrate the package from (jade/indigo) to became a package in kinetic?

That important because it's dependency for my quad-gazebo pacakge

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242250/can%27t-find-ros-package-in-kinetic-driver-base/) by [ROSOGUY](https://answers.ros.org/users/27820/rosoguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have similar problem with couple packages (usb_cam, dynamixel, urg_node).

In my case I had to download source from github into a workspace, and compile manually with catkin_make.

Having said that, I would like to update some packages into kinetic as well, some guidance would be great!

---

Originally posted by [Marcin Bogdanski](https://answers.ros.org/users/26406/marcin-bogdanski/) with karma: 231 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0